# What is a "point" in continuum mechanics?

Tags: continuum-mechanics

In continuum mechanics, a continuum is defined as a set of points filling a space (or a part of it). This seems a bit confusing to me since in a mathematical sense, points are zero-dimensional but concepts such as stresses (which are defined as force per area) or gravity (which affect masses/volumes) don't really make sense on "zero-dimensional" bodies. I know that a body can be divided into "cubes", which appear more and more like points as the length of their edges approaches $0$, yet in my mind, they remain three-dimensional. So shouldn't we rather say that continua consist of a set of infinitesimally small "cubes"? (Of course, each of these cubes has a center point...)

Comment: The problem is that "infinitesimally small" is a very slippery concept if you try to define it properly. (And so is "infinite" of course). If you want to get to the bottom of the math, you need a course in "real analysis" (not "calculus", where most courses just skate over the problem). But if you go down that path, expect to spend a few months learning things that are only useful to mathematicians, not physicists.

Comment: What is the difference between an infinitesimally small "cube" and a "zero-dimensional point"? As long as you don't provide mathematical definitions, this question remains unphysical. You want to discuss something very technical, without the technicality. Please provide your definitions as to initiate a proper discussion.

Comment: Yep, check that this belongs to math SE, not physics. You're kind of asking "how can a surface exist if any surface is made of points, which have no dimension".

Comment: Yeah, sadly I'm just an ignorant engineer (no sarcasm). As per my understanding, an infinitesimal volume would be defined as $dV=dxdydz$, whereas a point $P$ would be defined by its coordinates $(x|y|z)$ which should imply that $dV$ has a spatial extension and $P$ does not. Also, how can we define a stress (e. g. in $N/mm^2$) in a zero-dimensional point? But maybe there really is a lot more to the problem (If so, can someone recommend a book or sth.?). So maybe I should just accept that "$dV=P$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your question... and your comments...

You can build a $dV$ **around** a point.

Secondly, of course you can apply a stress on a point. Haven't you been "applying forces to a point" all the time? Because we've always taken cars and extense objects as points (particularly, placed at the Center of mass).

However, I think I get your point... the problem is "per unit area", right?

Well, it's true that this is usually conflicting at the beginning. The idea is that you should not be taking things "too seriously". We're used to the fact that "maths are exact", "sciences re exact, they are not poetry", and so on. Well, that's something you must blow down quickly. Science needs **approxiamtions**

You  know that a usual item has about $10^{24}$ atoms. How do I know? Well, it's of the order or 1 or two $mol$. Of course I'm not counting the atoms, it's a rough estimation that works.

So.. would you describe an object via describing the exact positions and the exact velcoities of all those molecules? Before you answer, remember that there are more atoms there than seconds in the age of the whole Universe.

So, of course reality is jsut impossible to handle. Fortunately, we don't need to do that. We create **an approximate model**.

In teh same way that we can say "a projectile follows a parabola". That's obviously not true, because of air friction, air lift, and many other effects. But **for all practical purpossess** (FAPP), it's mostly the parabola you're used to calculate.

In the same way, we are always constructing models. We know that matter is not continuos. MAtter is made of atoms. However, we treat it as a continuous medium. Why? Because we can approximate it to be continuum.

What's more... how can we define the stress? Well, we just compute the MEAN force on a surface, and then we make the area tend to 0.

So, basically, we can define the stress because we are **extrapolating** the mean force on big areas.

But check that the stress is not defined on a point of the real material. Teh stress is defined on an INVENTED surface. That surface has been invented by us, it does not exist: reality is a group of atoms. However, creating a surface "which behaves the same" is a useful TOOL that we use.

And how can we be sure that it behaves the same? Well, measuring it. Science is about doing experiments, about measuring things.

When we measure things, we are unavoidably measuring average quantities on a certain portion of matter... but that's probably what we need.

If you could measure the real "stress" on a material, it would probably be 0 at hollows and "a peak" on the atoms. So you'd have a very irregular function. That's not useful. We take the AVERAGES of that function, so that we can SMOOTH the functions.

So, instead of working with matter, we work with ideal continuous media where we can define continuous functions, with the hope that those functions are correctly measured so that the behavior is the same.

I hope this helped.

Note: however, you can goo deep in "how can a point create a line", in other words, how can size-less points create a line. Think of the line of real numbers... how can it be made up of poitns? That's another problem, but that's for mathematicians, ha ha.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know we can apply a force to a point (since it does not require an area of effect), but stress by definition does and thus cannot be applied to a point. It seems the "working hypothesis for engineers" is that for infinitesimal dimensions, the difference between looking at a point or a "cube" surrounding it vanishes. Concerning the difference between points and non-zero-dimensional entities (e. g. a line), there actually seem to be different definitions, some assuming lines to consist of points and some assuming them to be separate entities.

Comment: C. f. this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry). To me it seems to be a question of definition, which means any statement wether or not lines "are made up of points" would be an axiomatic one (of course in any case, points can be located on a line)